# React page refresh value get undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a list page and description page

1. ABC
2. Test ...

So when i click on ABC it will redirect to description page and list all details about ABC.so i did button click in

```
<Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/Viewpage",
        data: "ABC" // your data array of objects
      }}
    >
```

But in Holidayview component

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
          value:this.props.location.data,
      }
      
  }
  alertMessage(){
    console.log(this.state.value);
  }

    
    <button onClick={()=>{this.alertMessage()}}>click me to see log</button>
```

Which is working but when i refresh the page value seems undefined.

And i did another way like

```
<a href={`Viewpage?data=${n.id}`} ></a>
```

Here how can i get the url pass data ?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using react-router for routing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use params to access data on page refresh.

react-router-dom (v6) example:

```
//define route:
<Route
    path='example/:id/:name'
    element={<Example />} />

//navigate to route
<Link
    to='example/2/john'>
Example nav
</Link>

//in <Example> component:
const { id, name } = useParams()
```